# working on updating a deprecated method to a newer one within Jasmine getting errors for typescript

Tags: typescript, jasmine

working on updating this method
**throwOnExpectationFailure** to the newer one 
**oneFailurePerSpec**
the jasmine documents say to do this:

```
Use the `oneFailurePerSpec` option with Env#configure
```

Through research found this github issue on how to get this resolved: 
https://github.com/jasmine/jasmine.github.io/issues/102

in where I added the following to 
**helpers.js**

```
jasmine.getEnv().configure({
  failFast: false,
  hideDisabled: false,
  oneFailurePerSpec: false,
  random: true,
  seed: null, // null=random. Or use func: () => 4547;
  // specFilter: spec => spec.description.includes('NEEDLE'),
});
```

Which worked without any issues.

However, when I tried to do the same for 
**helpers.ts**

.getEnv has a red underline with the following error

```
property.getEnv does not exist on typeof Jasmine
```

Also, when I run npm test on the project
I get the following error from
**JasmineTestRunner.ts**

```
TypeError: jasmine.env.oneFailurePerSpec is not a function
```

additionally under
**JasmineTestRunner.spec.ts**

```
 beforeEach(() => {
    sandbox = sinon.createSandbox();
    jasmineStub = sandbox.createStubInstance(Jasmine);
    jasmineStub.env =  {
      oneFailurePerSpec: sandbox.stub()
    };
    evalGlobalStub = sandbox.stub(helpers, 'evalGlobal');
    sandbox.stub(helpers, 'Jasmine').returns(jasmineStub);
    fileNames = ['foo.js', 'bar.js'];
    clock = sandbox.useFakeTimers();
    sut = new JasmineTestRunner(fileNames, factory.strykerOptions({ jasmineConfigFile: 'jasmineConfFile' }));
  });
```

I get another red underline with the error:

```
 oneFailurePerSpec: sandbox.stub() is not assignable to type env
```

from

```
jasmineStub.env =  {
      oneFailurePerSpec: sandbox.stub()
    };
```

None of these errors are showing up under the .js files
which leads me to believe there is a setup issue or something out of date on the typescript side.

I've reviewed the jasmine documents to see if there is a different setup for typescript but I haven't been able to find any information.

My question is could someone help me figure out how to do the .getEnv() function call setup correctly in TS?

Thanks for any help provided!

Answer (score 0):

So I was very off on this one.

The change that needed to be made was to
**Jasmine.json**

and I added in this line:

```
"oneFailurePerSpec": false,
```

to here:

```
"helpers": [
    "helpers/**/*.js"
  ],
  "stopSpecOnExpectationFailure": false,
  "oneFailurePerSpec": false,
  "random": false
```

I then ran all the tests and confirmed everything worked.